# Create Generic Type with Generic Interface at Run Time

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, expression-trees

I've been working through an issue for a couple of hours now, and I think I'm close. I'm working on an app where we could have 50-100 types that perform the same way. So instead of creating 50-100 classes, I tried to make it generic and this is what I have:

This is the base class:

```
public class RavenWriterBase<T> : IRavenWriter<T> where T : class, IDataEntity
```

And this is the interface:

```
public interface IRavenWriter<T>
{
    int ExecutionIntervalInSeconds { get; }
    void Execute(object stateInfo);
    void Initialize(int executionIntervalInSeconds, Expression<Func<T, DateTime>> timeOrderByFunc);
}
```

And this is how I'm using it:

```
private static void StartWriters()
{
    Assembly assembly = typeof(IDataEntity).Assembly;
    List<IDataEntity> dataEntities = ReflectionUtility.GetObjectsForAnInterface<IDataEntity>(assembly);

    foreach (IDataEntity dataEntity in dataEntities)
    {
        Type dataEntityType = dataEntity.GetType();
        Type ravenWriterType = typeof(RavenWriterBase<>).MakeGenericType(dataEntityType);

        Expression<Func<IDataEntity, DateTime>> func = x => x.CicReadTime;

        // This is where I'm stuck. How do I activate this as RavenWriterBase<T>?
        var ravenWriter = Activator.CreateInstance(ravenWriterType);

        //ravenWriter.Initialize(60, func);  // I can't do this until I cast.

        // More functionality here (not part of this issue)
    }
}
```

I'm stuck on this line from above:

```
var ravenWriter = Activator.CreateInstance(ravenWriterType);
```

**This is my question:**
**How can I use that as RavenWriterBase or IRavenWriter? Something like:**

```
ravenWriter.Initialize(60, func);
```

I think it needs to be something like this, but I need to specify a type for IRavenWriter<> and I don't know it yet:

```
var ravenWriter = Activator.CreateInstance(ravenWriterType) as IRavenWriter<>;
```

If I hover over ravenWriter, I successfully have my object:

[image]

But now I need to be able to use it in a generic way. How can I do that?

**Update:**

I just thought of using the dynamic keyword, and this works:

```
dynamic ravenWriter = Activator.CreateInstance(ravenWriterType);
ravenWriter.Initialize(60);
```

I cheated a bit because I realized that the Func was the same for each IDataEntity, so that wasn't necessary to pass as a parameter to Initialize(). However, at least now I *can* call Initialize(). But now that the Func is the same, I shouldn't need the generic interface either.

Comment: Sounds like improper use of generics.  When you are finding yourself needing to run different methods based on different types, but the types are known only at runtime, you want to make use of polymorphism.  What is the generics gaining you?  Can you run the methods as-is without generics in the first place, i.e., with IDataEntity?

Comment: I agree with mellamokb.  However, if you're set on generics, why not create a wrapper class that you can instantiate non-genarically.  The wrapper should have a method that returns an instance of RavenWriterBase<Type> depending on the type passed in as an argument.  Then, instantiate the wrapper and call the method with the requestedd type as the parameter.  This will require a large switch statement, but at least not 200 separate classes.

Comment: Do you create other Expressions not using IDataEntity for T? Or is T always an IDataEntity? And if T is always IDataEntity, why use generics?

Comment: @DavidCowden: Good idea, and it's actually not that hard, because this is made trivial and easily maintained with T4-templates, which we use all the time.

Comment: @mellamokb I'm not running different methods based on different types. I must not have been clear. I don't see where you see that. I want to call Initialize() and Execute() on each instance.

Comment: @DanBusha I need generics because I'm saving each type to RavenDB. There will be another service that pulls that data by type.

Comment: Write more code, uncomment it probably, to make clear where is the problem. What are you trying to achieve and where is the problem??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution would be to:

- Create a non-generic interface of `IRavenWriter`
- Make `IRavenWriter<T>` inherit from `IRavenWriter`
- Keep `Execute` and `ExecutionIntervalInSeconds` in `IRavenWriter`
- Make `IRavenWriter` have `Func<DateTime>` and use that in your writer
- Move `Initialize` to `IRavenWriter<T>`
- Use a factory to initialise the Func according to the type and expression:

For example:

```
public class MyDateTime
{
    public DateTime This { get; set; }
}

public static Func<DateTime> GetFunk<T>(Expression<Func<T, DateTime>> timeOrderByFunc, T t)
{
    return () => timeOrderByFunc.Compile()(t);
}
```

And you use:

```
GetFunk<MyDateTime>(x => x.This, new MyDateTime(){This = DateTime.Now});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. How does that allow me to use ravenWriter as either RavenWriterBase<> or IRavenWriter<>?

Comment: @BobHorn it does not. You cannot have a knowledge of `RavenWriterBase<>` in there. Instead you need to use `IRavenWriterBase` (non-generic) in there. Compile-time knowledge of the type does not exist in there so you cannot cast.

Comment: Thank you. I just edited my question to show how I can call Initialize() by using dynamic. I think that should work.

Comment: @BobHorn the `dynamic` keyword doesn't really fix the problem. Your type hierarchy is still messed up, but instead of dealing with it, you just ignore the type system. Not really a solution IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really hard to turn run-time `Type` into compile-time generic Type parameter. Just introduce new interface for creating/initializing your objects:

```
interface IRawenWriterFactory
{
  object Create();
}

class RawenWriterFactory<T> : IRawenWriterFactory
{
  public object Create()
  {
    Expression<Func<IDataEntity, DateTime>> func = x => x.CicReadTime;

    var ravenWriter = new RavenWriterBase<T>();
    ravenWriter.Initialize(60, func);

    return ravenWriter;
  }
}
```

Now just create `RawenWriterFactory` with dataEntityType just like you've created `ravenWriter` and use it via non-generic IRavenWriterFactory interface.

However, there could be simpler solutions if you'll change your design. E.g. if you turn Initialize method into constructor you'll be able to pass func as Activator.CreateInstance parameter and you wouldn't need to use generic interface for initialization at all.